# How do you convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timestamp, varchar

You'd like to call a stored proc on MS SQL that has a parameter type of TIMESTAMP within T-SQL, not ADO.NET using a VARCHAR value (e.g. '0x0000000002C490C8').

What do you do?

UPDATE:
This is where you have a "Timestamp" value coming at you but exists only as VARCHAR.  (Think OUTPUT variable on another stored proc, but it's fixed already as VARCHAR, it just has the value of a TIMESTAMP).  So, unless you decide to build Dynamic SQL, how can you programmatically change a value stored in VARCHAR into a valid TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Is that value like the number of milliseconds since the epoch?

Comment: No, it's database-wide unique identifier. The name timestamp is something of a misnomer; it's more akin to what other DBs call a rowid.

Comment: OK, sorry, not as up on MS SQL's datatypes as I should be!

Comment: Not a problem, it confuses me too. (And I only was able to be "fastest gun in the west" here because I was literally just doing this research the other day for a table in a project I inherited ... :)

Comment: Oooh ... the update makes this much trickier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timestamp datatype is managed by SQL Server.  I've never seen it used anywhere other than as a table column type.  In that capacity, the column of type timestamp will give you a rigorous ordinal of the last insert/update on the row in relation to all other updates in the database.  To see the most recent ordinal across the entire database, you can retrieve the value of @@DBTS or rowversion().

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(SQL.90).aspx

> timestamp (Transact-SQL)
>
>
> is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type.

Hence, the volatile value of a timestamp column cannot be set and is subject to change upon any modifaction to the row.  You can, however, freeze the timestamp value to a varbinary(8) value.

For example, say you had a source table and a target table.

```
CREATE TABLE tblSource (
Id int not null
colData int not null
colTimestamp timestamp null)

CREATE TABLE tblTarget (
Id int not null
colData int not null
colTimestampVarBinary varbinary(8) null)
```

Then, in an extraction process, you might want to capture everything that has been updated since the last time you ran the extraction process.

```
DECLARE @maxFrozenTargetTimestamp varchar(8)
SELECT @maxFrozenTargetTimestamp = max(colStamp) FROM tblTarget

INSERT tblTarget(Id, colData, colTimestampVarBinary)
SELECT 
Id
,colData
colTimestampVarBinary = convert(varbinary(8) colTimestamp)
FROM 
tblSource 
WHERE
tblSource.colTimestamp > @maxFrozenTargetTimestamp
```

If you are having issues, my first guess would be that crux of your problem
is in the conversion of a varchar to a varbinary(8), and not to a timestamp type.

For more info (perhaps too much) , see the comment (fourth one down) I left to the blog post http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2004/10/about-timestamp-datatype-of-sql-server.html?showComment=1213612020000

Answer (score 6):

Since timestamp is compatible with varbinary the solution will be this in SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @hexstring varchar(max);
set @hexstring = '0xabcedf012439';
select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 1);

set @hexstring = 'abcedf012439';
select CONVERT(varbinary(max), @hexstring, 2);
```

Reference. [MSN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A TIMESTAMP is semantically equivalent to VARBINARY(8) (nullable) or BINARY(8) (non-nullable). So you should be able to call the procedure with the parameter unquoted, as follows:

```
EXEC usp_MyProc @myParam=0x0000000002C490C8
```

See also [SQL Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx)

EDIT for updated question ...

I just tried a few experiments. Frankly, I'm curious as to how you got this represented as a varchar in the first place, since when I do something like:

```
select top 10 convert(varchar, ts) from foo
```

Where ts is a timestamp, I get 10 blank rows. (If I don't convert, I see my timestamps.)

However, I tried working at it from the proper direction ... I did this:

```
select convert(timestamp, '0x0000000000170B2E')
```

And the conversion resulted in `0x3078303030303030`. So that won't play either. Nor will converting to binary.

I hate to say it, but you might be stuck in a dynamic SQL world. I'd **really** like to be wrong, though.

Comment: Please see updated Question.  Sorry it wasn't clear before.  Imagine getting a parameter passed in as VARCHAR (but it has a TIMESTAMP value inside it).  How would you make @myParam then?