# Getting the data type of a ResultSet column

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using SQL Server. My table has a column with the data type `datetime2`.

I am accessing the table data using `ResultSet`. I need to get the data type of a column. The method `rs.getColumnTypeName()` returns `nvarchar` for database data type `datetime2`.

Is there any way to get `datetime2` or `Timestamp` for the same?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/220226/579580

Comment: Hi, the issue you are experiencing is most likely related to the JDBC driver of SQL Server you are using.
Download the latest version 6.0 type 4.2 , if you can.
In this version of SQL Server driver you will be able to get:
(a) metaData.getColumnType = 93 - in 2.0 you -9 (b) metaData.getColumnClassName(...) / java.sql.Timestamp . In short, datetime2 are not properly supported by driver version 2.0. So you should not use datetime2 with that older driver version. Try upgrading to get proper metadata and results.

Answer (score 19):

If you are doing it in Java, there is a class `ResultSetMetaData`.

You can use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName()` to get the fully qualified name of the class.

For example, if the datatype in database is `VARCHAR`, the value returned is `java.lang.String`.

Also try using `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel()` - see whether its applicable in your case.

[Java Documentation for ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: You can also get the integer value from `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()` and compare it with one of the constants in `java.sql.Types` to check whether it is a particular type. This is closer to the database schema itself as you can distinguish between various database types (e.g. `NVARCHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `INTEGER`, `NUMERIC`) that all resolve to the same Java type (e.g. `String`, `int`).

Comment: His problem I believe is that the metadata makes no sense for the actual DB column. The Microsft sqlserver column is a DATETIME2. But despite that, the returned type by the resultset is a "string" and the type for the column is nvarchar. This most likely a bug with the JDBC driver version (e.g JDBC driver version 2)