# Convert function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the data of a column from varchar(255) to Timestamp.

I went to Microsoft documentation and it's not working

Code:

```
SELECT 
    ["Data Nascimento"] 
FROM
    [leoninos] AS Original, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ["Data Nascimento"]) AS VARCHAR, 
    CONVERT(timestamp(6, 4), ["Data Nascimento"]) AS timestamp;
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 53.
>   Incorrect syntax next to keyword 'CONVERT'.

What is the syntax error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `timestamp` **is not** a date-time column type! The type-name `timestamp` is actually a synonym for `rowversion` which is a special built-in type that behaves similarly to a serial-number. I think you want `datetime` or `datetime2` instead. (in SQL Server 2008 the `timestamp` name was officially deprecated to help prevent this confusion).

Comment: Also you have your two `CONVERT` statements in the `FROM` block of your query - I *presume* these should really be in the `SELECT` portion of your statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP in MSSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191159/how-do-you-convert-varchar-to-timestamp-in-mssql)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `varchar` and `timestamp` as column aliases.  Try this:

```
SELECT ["Data Nascimento"] as original
       TRY_CONVERT(varchar(255), ["Data Nascimento"]) AS type_varchar 
       -- TRY_CONVERT(timestamp(6, 4), ["Data Nascimento"]) AS type_timestamp
FROM [leoninos] ;
```

Notes:

- `timestamp` isn't really appropriate.  I don't know what you are trying to do.
- The `FROM` clause goes after the `SELECT` list.
- Don't use SQL keywords as column names (even if they are not reserved).
- Use `try_convert()` in case the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are doing- but it appears that you are trying to select a table and also two scalars at once.  Try just doing the CONVERT statements on their own with sample values:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, '10'), CONVERT(date, '20180720')
```

Then, once you have it working for some sample values, you can convert column values:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (a NVARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('january 1 2018')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('20180720')

SELECT a, CONVERT(date, a) FROM #test
DROP TABLE #test
```